# Chrome is pixelating/mangling images with nested CSS scales applied

Tags: google-chrome, css, webkit, css-transforms

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZArwT/18/

I'm working on a project where I need to have several nested divs scaling relative to each other.

A parent div is scaled up 10x and rotated, and then a child div of that parent is counter-rotated to normalize rotation, and then a child of THAT is scaled to .1x to normalize its scale.

All images are high res pngs.

In Chrome, the child image appears badly pixelated and mangled, as though the software tried to scale up a really tiny image.

In every other browser (even, gasp, IE) the image appears crystal clear and sharp (as it "should", since it is displaying at a size lower than it's actual resolution).

If you check the above fiddle in Firefox, IE, or Safari, you'll see that the guy in the bright hoody looks sharp and clear.

If you look at the fiddle in Chrome, you'll see the guy in the hoody looking mangled and pixelated.

Unfortunately, I cannot create the image at the optimal max size to begin with as it is designed to scale up from a relatively small size to cover the whole screen.

I've looked all over and tried multiple solutions including "image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;", and using "webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d" in various incarnations.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="frame"></div>

<div class="frameInner">
  <div class="counterRotate"> <!--normalizes coordinates for content so that x and y are really x and y instead of diagonals -->
    <div class="content">
      <img class="guy" src="http://abraxasleads.com/misc/chromeImageSmash/guy.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 718px;
  height: 800px;  
}

.frame {
  display: block;
  width: 718px;
  height: 800px;
  background: url('http://abraxasleads.com/misc/chromeImageSmash/frame.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.frameInner {
  display: block;
  width: 470px;
  height: 573px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 114px;
  left: 123px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.counterRotate {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: block;
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  background: url('http://abraxasleads.com/misc/chromeImageSmash/content.png');
  position: absolute;
  top: -483px;
  left: -898.5px;
}

.guy {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

JS:

```
var frame = $('.frame'),
    frameInner = $('.frameInner'),
    counterRotate = $('.counterRotate'),
    content = $('.content'),
    guy = $('.guy'),
    frameRotation = -45,
    counterRotation = 45;

frame.css({
  "webkitTransform" : 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateZ('+ frameRotation +'deg) scale(10, 10)',
  "msTransform" : 'translate(0px, 0px) scale(10, 10) rotate('+ frameRotation +'deg)',
   "-moz-Transform" : 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateZ('+ frameRotation +'deg) scale(10, 10)'
})

frameInner.css({
  "webkitTransform" : 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateZ('+ frameRotation +'deg) scale(10, 10)',
  "msTransform" : 'translate(0px, 0px) scale(10, 10) rotate('+ frameRotation +'deg) ',
  "-moz-transform" : 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) rotateZ('+ frameRotation +'deg) scale(10, 10)'
})

counterRotate.css({
  "webkitTransform" : 'translate3d(0px, 60px, 0px) rotateZ('+ counterRotation +'deg)',
  "msTransform" : 'translate(0px, 60px) rotate('+ counterRotation +'deg)',
  "-moz-transform" : 'translate3d(0px, 60px, 0px) rotateZ('+ counterRotation +'deg)'
})

guy.css({
   "webkitTransform" : 'translate3d(-120px, -200px, 0px) scale(.1,.1)',
   "msTransform" : 'translate(-120px, -200px) scale(.1,.1)',
   "-moz-transform" : 'translate3d(-120px, -200px, 0px) scale(.1,.1)'
})
```

Answer (score 2):

When scaling images, Webkit rasterizes the images, causing pixelation. To prevent this, start with an initial scale below 1 (let's say 0.1), and then have the final enlarged version have a scale of 1. This way, the rendering engine renders the image at its full size and shrinks it and when scaled, it does not create the pixelation you mentioned.

Comment: this is such a crap behavior, makes me furious.